# options module_mapper not resolving on sibling projects

Tags: flowtype

I have an issue with module resolution in a project, I reproduced the error in this repo: https://github.com/melloc01/flowconfig-module_mapper but it's simple so I'll try to explain:

The directory structure is like this:

```
> common/
   .flowconfig
    /core/
         service.js
    /modules/
         widget.js

> project_1
    .flowconfig
    app.js
```

with the following flowconfigs:

**common**'s:

```
[options]
module.name_mapper='^core\/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/core/\1'
```

**project_1**'s:

```
[options]
module.name_mapper='^core\/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/../common/core/\1'
```

Both common/modules/widget.js and project_1/app.js have the same source code:

```
// @flow
import service from "core/service";
```

but Flow trows an error on project_1, am I missing something?

[image]

[image]